# Chained branching merging strategy

Tags: git, merge

I created branch A from master. After finishing I created pull request to master. While work from A was under review I started working on task that is based on branch A, so from branch A I created branch B. Then I merged branch B to A and wanted to merge B to master, but conflict appeared. What is best practice to avoid conflict in this scenario? Both branches were local, before pull request from A.

[edit]

Any same line was edited in both branches A and B, so why it is not merged automatically?

[image]

Comment: I would recommend using GitFlow as you asked for best practice. This way you will never branch from a feature branch (A) but from develop and all the merges are done through develop reducing code conflict risk.

Comment: `wanted to merge B to master` ... why?  I think `B` should go back to `A`.  Note in general that there isn't always a way to avoid merge conflicts.

Comment: Why are you wanting to avoid conflicts? Such is the nature of a DVCS.

Comment: Yes B merged with A and there was not conflicts, but then I want to make pull request, so I wanted to merge B to master, because I wanted base branch pointing to master.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Because I was working on features locally, so this is why conflicts seems strange.

Comment: Not really, if you change the same file in two different commits (on the same line) and then merge, one would expect a conflict.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Git* (emphasis required here, because you are probably using more than just Git itself) doesn't have a concept of a "base branch".

When you use a web interface like those on GitHub or Bitbucket to create a "pull request", it's the *web interface* that chooses the upstream's branch name against which to suggest the pull request.  Git itself has no idea that you will make a pull request.<sup>1</sup>  All Git knows and cares about are the commits, usually by hash ID.

When you run `git merge`, *you* choose two commits, usually two branch tips.  You choose one by running `git checkout`, typically `git checkout <somebranch>`.  That commit becomes your *current commit*.  This is the commit that Git calls *local* or `--ours`; I generally call it *L* for left, local, or `--ours`.  (Note that if you don't run `git checkout` just before `git merge`, whatever you have checked out right now *remains* your current commit, and you are therefore choosing *that* as your *L* commit.)

You then run `git merge <name-or-hash-id>`.  Git translates the name, if you give it one, to a commit hash ID.  This is how you choose the other commit, which Git sometimes calls the *remote* or *other* or `--theirs` commit, and I call *R*.

Git uses the *L* and *R* commit hash IDs, plus all the *other* commits in the repository, to find a *merge base* commit hash ID.  This merge base commit is, in short, the "nearest" commit at which the two branches "come back together".  ***The commit that Git will find here depends on the topology of the existing commit graph.***

If Git is able to do the merge on its own, Git makes a new commit holding the merge result.  The new commit has two parents, instead of just one: the *first* parent is the commit that was *L* at the time you ran `git merge`, and the second is the commit that was *R*.  The new commit goes on the current branch, so that the current branch name—the one you have checked out—now points to the new merge commit.

The graph you drew above is hard for me to interpret: I cannot tell, from your drawing, which commits are reachable from which branch-tip commits, or for that matter, which commits are the branch tips in the first place.  In particular you have drawn two commits that appear to be merge commits, but I do not know whether earlier (ancestor) commits are on the left or the right.  Moreover, your text describes making *one* merge, not two.  Using the assumption that earlier commits are towards the left—that time flows left-to-right, as it were—here is how I might draw most of this graph in text:

```
       o--o   o--o   <-- branch-B
      /    \ /
     | __---o   <-- branch-A
     |/
...--o   <-- master
```

Note, however, that *this* graph has only *one* merge commit, which in this case is the commit to which the name `branch-A` points.  The name `branch-B` points to the right-most commit on the top line.

In this particular example, `branch-B` contains *every commit drawn in the graph*, while `branch-A` contains all but the two most recent commits, and `master` contains only the commits on the bottom line plus any earlier commits leading up to that point.  The merge base of the tip commit of `branch-B` (commit *L*) and the tip commit of `master` (commit *R*) would be the tip commit of `master`, i.e., commit *R* itself.  Running `git merge` while on branch `branch-B` would therefore choose that as the merge base.  The merge would be trivial to make (but in fact refused) as there would be no merge conflicts.<sup>2</sup>  So that's clearly not what you are doing, and clearly not the correct graph.

Without the correct graph, it's impossible to say what Git chose as the merge base.  But if you did get a merge conflict, it is because when comparing the merge base commit to commit *L*, Git saw one change to some line of some file, and then when comparing the merge base commit to commit *R*, Git saw a *different* change to the *same* line of the *same* file.  Git was unable to choose between these two changes, so it stopped with a merge conflict, leaving the work-tree version of the file with both changes applied.  It is now up to you to resolve this conflict (and any other conflicts), `git add` the correct merge result, and run `git merge --continue` to finish the merge; or run `git merge --abort` to stop the merge and put things back to the way they were before Git attempted the merge.

---

<sup>1</sup>While they are related, don't confuse these externally-provided web interfaces with the `git request-pull` command-line command.  That one *is* built in to Git, but it requires that *you*, not Git, choose the `<start>` commit.  When GitHub makes the choice for you, they are using information not available to Git itself.  Specifically, GitHub knows—has recorded for itself, in a location it effectively keeps secret from Git—which upstream project you used when you clicked the GitHub "fork" button.  They (GitHub) also control the Git repository for that upstream project, so they can peek inside it and choose a `<start>`.  But *they* do that; Git doesn't.

<sup>2</sup>Remember, after computing the merge base commit, Git effectively runs:

```
git diff --find-renames <base> L   # see what we did on --ours
git diff --find-renames <base> R   # see what they did on --theirs
```

and then tries to combine these two sets of changes into one big "everyone's changes since the base" change-set, and apply the *combined* changes to whatever is in the `<base>` commit.  We have just made the claim that `<base>` and *R* are *the same commit*, so there must be no changes at all here.  The result of such a merge would match commit *L* exactly.  In fact, though, Git would say "already up to date" and refuse to do anything, for this case.